# Why do I get an "undefined index" error when trying to save multiple objects to database in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm building an application where schools will register students to participate in a sport event.

It works fine to register one student at at time, but I want the user to choose how many students they want to register at the same time.

In the registration they need to check the different sports that the student will participate in.

When trying to post to the database, I get this error:

> Undefined Index: memberSports

I've searched on different sites but can't seem to find a solution.

Here is my blade view (`$numberOfMembers`, `$sports`, `$school`, `$city`, `$contactName`, `$contactEmail` and `$contactPhone` variables are returned from another view):

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
        <h1>Registration</h1>
      </x-slot>
    

<form action="{{ route('member.store') }}" method="post">
@csrf
@for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfMembers; $i++)
<h1>Person {{ $i }}</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="member[{{ $i }}][school]" value="{{ $school }}">
<input type="hidden" name="member[{{ $i }}][city]" value="{{ $city }}">
<input type="hidden" name="member[{{ $i }}][contactName]" value="{{ $contactName }}">
<input type="hidden" name="member[{{ $i }}][contactPhone]" value="{{ $contactPhone }}">
<input type="hidden" name="member[{{ $i }}][contactEmail]" value="{{ $contactEmail }}">

<label for="member[{{ $i }}][name]">Name::</label>
<input type="text" name="member[{{ $i }}][name]">
<label for="member[{{ $i }}][gender]">Gender:</label>
<select name="member[{{ $i }}][gender]">
<option>Boy</option>
<option>Girl</option>
<option>Other</option>

</select>

Sports:
@foreach ($sports as $sport)
<input type="checkbox" name="member[{{ $i }}][memberSports[]]" value="{{ $sport->id }}">
<label for="member[{{ $i }}][memberSports[]]">{{ $sport->name }}</label>
@endforeach
<br>
@endfor
<input type="submit" value="Register all members">
</form> 
</x-app-layout>
```

And here is the store method in the controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach($request->member as $member)
    {
        $newMember = new Member([
        'name' => $member['name'],
        'gender' => $member['gender'],
        'school' => $member['school'],
        'city' => $member['city'],
        'contactName' => $member['contactName'],
        'contactPhone' => $member['contactPhone'],
        'contactEmail' => $member['contactEmail'],
            
        ]);
        $newMember->save();
    
foreach($member['memberSports'] as $sport)        
{     
$newMember->sports()->attach($sport);
}        
    }
return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: I found your form construction a bit weird. For example `name="member[{{ $i }}][memberSports[]]"`. Shouldn't that just be `name="member[{{ $i }}]`? I hope somebody proves me wrong. Because in your posted code, I have no idea why one student passes the test but multiple don't.

Comment: Try to post a `dd($request)` for one student and a `dd($request)` for multiple students. Somebody will figure it out. I think it's because of a multidimensional array post, but this doesn't explain why it works for 1 student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting the same input name, creating one student's worth of sports, rather than creating an array for each student within this line:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="member[{{ $i }}][memberSports[]]" value="{{ $sport->id }}">
```

If you're goal in the controller is to loop on a set of `member[id]['membersports']`, try moving the empty array outside the inner array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="member[{{ $i }}][memberSports][]" value="{{ $sport->id }}">
```

Though I agree with the comment above - this is unusual construction, with the mutli-level array.  If possible, simplify.

Comment: Thanks very much! Your solution works fine! I'm a quite new developer so apologise for a newbie question! :)